# how to pass parameter from c++ to linux shell

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell, g++

My question may be simple but I couldn't find what I wanted in the forums.

I write c++ programs and I have learned the general rules recently. Also, I usually program in a linux environment and use g++(c++) compiler.

I want something that while a c++ program is running, it passes some parameters to linux command window and executes some commands on there. After all of these jobs, it turns itself with some parameters.

Particularly, the c++ program obtains very specific data(such as an integer sensor data) and passes it to a command line and maybe to a shell script, after that, gets the result of the shell script (such as an error code like int 0 or 1). I want to write program that interacts well with shell.

More particularly, if you write a=3 to linux commad line there will be a local parameter named a and its value is 3. I want to pass this 3 value from c++ program. I desire that if there would be a function like:

```
int value=3;            
system("a=%d",value); //(notice:this is not a real code!)
```

I hope I could explain my request. I am sorry if I said something that is wrong but as I said I am a new c++ programmer.

note: 
I used some functions of sys/syscall.h and stdlib.h libraries.

Comment: Are you looking for `setenv`, by any chance?

Comment: In most cases the `system()` call should receive a string like you enter it from your command line prompt, Feel free to construct such string using the `std::string` class and pass the result using the `c_str()` function to `system()`.

Comment: If you are programming in C++, why the C language tag?  For example, the C++ language has `std::string` whereas C doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In C

```
int value = 3;
char command[255];
sprintf (command, "a = %d\n", value);
int result = system (command);
```

### In C++

```
int value = 3;
std::stringstream ss ("a = "); //include <sstream>!
ss << value;
int result = system (ss.str ().c_str ());
```

Comment: Answer could be improved by showing how to capture the process exit code (it's just the return value of `system`).

Comment: Thanks sir, your codes work well, i learned a new class through it.